# How to block scroll event passing through to iframe until iframe is active?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long scrolling page. On this scrolling page is an iframe that has a media app that has media that zooms in and out when it receives a scroll event.

If a user is using the mousewheel to scroll the pareent page, eventually they will hit the iframe, at which case the page will stop scrolling and the iframe will zoom into the media app very far.

If I disable mouse events for the iframe, then the user can never zoom in or click around the media app.

Is there a way to prevent default scroll action on iframe and have it only occur when the iframe is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following steps:

1. Wrap your `iframe` inside `div` element. You can't use `onclick` method of iframe.
2. Change `pointer-events` property of `iframe` element when events (click, mouselive) are fired on parent `div` element.

Here is the JQuery example:

```
    $('#iframeContainer').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#iframe').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
    });

    $('#iframeContainer').mouseleave(function(event) { 
        $('#iframe').css('pointer-events', 'none'); 
    });
```

Comment: Very smart. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Without testing I see two ways to solve this

1) Give the iframe the css value `pointer-events: none;` and set the value back to auto when its active

```
iframe {
    pointer-events: none;
}
iframe:active {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

2) Remove the eventlistener of the iframe via JavaScript and bind them again as soon the iframe is active.